# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath' on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**I got this error when opening Android Studio**.

I've never gotten this error before. I've tried cleaning and re-synchronizing `gradle`, I've updated all packages in SDK Manager,

I've restarted my Android Studio,

I've run it as administrator,

I also have tried building a new project, but this error won't go away.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```js
Error:Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4' when creating directory 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401'
```

**[UPDATE]**

After I've tried rebuilding my project, I got a new error like this.

```js
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'BPSGoSurvey'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         :BPSGoSurvey:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.3.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
         :BPSGoSurvey:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.3.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
      > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
         > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
                  > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download8245895784892794258bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download3502880229047415896bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
      > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
                  > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download6416635460030578050bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download916061549622655000bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
     Required by:
         :BPSGoSurvey:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.3.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
      > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
         > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
                  > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download8269455495978527180bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download3692548803835443828bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
      > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
                  > Could not parse POM file:/E:/Android%20Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download5076305514553905674bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom' 
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:11.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:4.
                           > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom'.
                              > Failed to move file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download1507005468069947828bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache\apache\4\602b647986c1d24301bc3d70e5923696bc7f1401\apache-4.pom'
```

Comment: try deleting that modules-2 folder, it's where gradle temporarily saves the files it grabs from repos, and double check that you don't have anything wonky in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @quidproquo I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since its a gradle cache directory, try deleting it (or its parent directory) forcefully. Some other process may have locked that directory not allowing Studio to access it. After deleting, close all processes associated with Android Studio (adb, studio.exe, java.exe, etc). Then try restarting Studio.

Comment: I already deleted cache directory, but it still didn't work :(

Comment: Did you also try deleting the `/.gradle/` directory?

Comment: I can't delete gradle directory, it says it is because the directory isn't empty

Comment: You should be able to delete it. Try safemode/command prompt/restart/etc. depending on your OS.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. I got a new error when I tried rebuilding my project. Is that error the same as old error?

Comment: This happened after deleting the `.gradle/`? Also, update the question with your OS info and Android Studio version for others to help.

Comment: try running android studio with admininstrative/root rights